# Conflicting libraries error in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, google-search-api, conflicting-libraries

I'm trying to install a library and run it on PyCharm. Tried to install it through PyCharm but I wasn't able, some error happened:

```
Collecting Google-Search-API
Using cached Google-Search-API-1.1.13.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/5t/y8w_0_2j52l866cgl2p2q0nm0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging0.tmp/Google-Search-API/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    with open("test_requirements.txt") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_requirements.txt'
```

Together with the error message there was a sugestion:

> "Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you
>   use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter
>   located at
>   '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'."

Cool. So I went to terminal, did a `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5:$PATH` to make sure that pip was sending the lib to the right place.

After tried `pip install Google-Search-API`, all seemed alright:

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ santanna_santanna$ pip install Google-Search-API
Requirement already satisfied: Google-Search-API in /anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

No errors, all cool.

So I went back to PyCharm and, as suggested in the [Google-Search-API GitHub][1] typed:

```
import google
```

And got:

```
ImportError: No module named 'google'
```

I've been burning my brains to install that and use on PyCharm.

Note: After doing the `export PATH=...` on terminal I did a `which python` and the answer terminal gave me was `//anaconda/bin/python`

**EDIT**

Tried `sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -m pip install Google-Search-API` and the error I got was very similar to the one on PyCharm:

```
The directory '/Users/santanna_santanna/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/santanna_santanna/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting Google-Search-API
  Downloading Google-Search-API-1.1.13.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-j2qk3_00/Google-Search-API/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        with open("test_requirements.txt") as f:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_requirements.txt'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-j2qk3_00/Google-Search-API/
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Did you set the correct *Python* interpreter for your *PyCharm* project?

Comment: @CristiFati my PyCharm project is using Python 3.5.0. Is that your question?

Comment: No, as you might have multiple *Python3.5.0* installed. I didn't work with *Anaconda*, i imagine it's something similar to *VEnv*: there you can have multiple virtual python environments, each with its own set of libraries installed. You must pick the **exact** one that you need (e.g. going by path).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is in alpha status and only supports Python 2, according to its PyPI page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Google-Search-API. That's probably the reason why it installs with errors.

I would suggest to either use an alternative solution to query the Google search API, or switch to Python 2 if you absolutely must use this package.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you changed to another possibility, but for others who want develop in python3

Install package

```
unidecode (py -3.5 -m pip install unidecode)
selenium  (py -3.5 -m pip install selenium)
bs4       (py -3.5 -m pip install bs4)
```

and then insert following command (ensure, that you have installed git)

```
py -3.5 -m pip install git+https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API/
```

command:

`py -3.5 -m pip`

for python version 3.5, it´s a comfort method if you deal with multiple python version so it will be call the pip from python 3.5 directory

It is downloaded from the github repo, in this case i had no problem with the missing .txt file and works perfect for me

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks for that. Could you provide the exact synthax you use to install using this py command? Tried that and my terminal is saying "py: command not found"

Comment: This commands works for windows machines. For linux is similar syntax available: `python3.6 -m pip --version` printed out `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`. So i think, that on macos have to be a similar syntax available. I have no macos to test it. So try the command `python3` or `python3.5` before the -m statement.